# How to use JsonSlurper?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I have written a test case  in SOAP UI which creates a user and returns the Id. This is the JsonResponse. Through a Groovy script, I need to extract the **id**

```
{
    "schemas":["urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation"],
    "urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation":
        [
            {
                "meta":{ 
                    "resourceType":"UserInvitation",                                                   
                    "lastModified":"2015-12-22T07:45:30Z",
                    "location":"https://test-ma.api.assaabloy.com/credential-management/customer/663/invitation/2643209"
                },
                "invitationCode":"FBXO-SRWS-LKFI-ZKZI",
                "status":"PENDING",
                "createdDate":"2015-12-22T02:45:30Z",
                "expirationDate":"2015-12-22T02:45:30Z",
                "id":2643209
             }
         ]
}
```

I'm very new to Groovy. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = """
{
    "schemas":["urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation"],
    "urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation":
        [
            {
                "meta":{ 
                    "resourceType":"UserInvitation",                                                   
                    "lastModified":"2015-12-22T07:45:30Z",
                    "location":"https://test-ma.api.assaabloy.com/credential-management/customer/663/invitation/2643209"
                },
                "invitationCode":"FBXO-SRWS-LKFI-ZKZI",
                "status":"PENDING",
                "createdDate":"2015-12-22T02:45:30Z",
                "expirationDate":"2015-12-22T02:45:30Z",
                "id":2643209
             }
         ]
}"""
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
assert 2643209 == slurped."urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation"[0].id
```

`new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)` statement will return an instance of the map interface. So using this map you can get the list with this statement: `slurped."urn:hid:scim:api:ma:1.0:UserInvitation"`, then the first element using `getAt` operator (`[0]`) and finally with `id` you get the desired value.